# Using PHP - is it possible to set SessionStorage in the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, session-storage

Im pulling in a `$_SESSION` variable coming from my database, either: `$_SESSION['lvl']`.

After the level is fetched, I'd like to store that variable in the browser's session as key value pairs using the `sessionStorage` API; is this possible?

I do not see any docs or info as it looks like this is only possible using JavaScript.

I'd like to set it within my PHP service.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: PHP code runs on the server.  It can't access the browser's session storage.  (But PHP code can output `<script>` tags with JavaScript code to be run later, in the browser.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to produce Javascript code that will do it on the client, and it's gonna be a pain to get the value on the server side.

Comment: Ok i figured this would need to be handled on the client side. I will go back to the drawing board. Thanks @zneak for not being a prick about answering a simple question.

Comment: actually not, you will have to insert some hidden input fields that you will set with javascript